# MS Office runs configuration after DLL update?

Tags: dll, batch-file, ms-office

I am currently supporting a Microsoft Access 2000 line of business application with a number of external dependencies, including Microsoft Word 2007 for mail merges. The application uses a batch script to keep external references up to date by copying and registering (if needed) each DLL on the user's computer, something like the script below:

```
COPY "\\fileshare\references\fileX.dll" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\fileX.dll"
regsvr32 "C:\WINDOWS\system32\fileX.dll"
```

Here are the DLL's affected:

- comdlg32.ocx (registered)
- mscomctl.ocx (registered)
- stdole2.tlb
- MS09.dll
- MSACC9.OLB
- msoutl.olb
- MSWORD.OLB
- VBE6.DLL (registered)
- dao360.dll (registered)
- msado21.tlb

More often than not the batch script simply replaces a user's DLL with the same version of the same DLL. However, for some reason after this batch script executes and a user tries to open a document in Office 2007, a configuration wizards pops up and steals focus from the document only to require a reboot to finish.

While this isn't really a critical work-stopping issue, it is certainly an annoyance. The obvious guess is that it is one of the Office 2007 DLL's, but I haven't been able to isolate which DLL is the culprit.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my understanding that you should not be distributing the OLB files. They are included in the install of Office, and will already be present on any workstation that has office installed.

You also should not be installing any ADO, DAO, or any other MDAC/WDAC components manually.
For older OS's, you should run an installer (`MDAC_TYP.EXE`) that installs the entire set of Data Access Components; google for `MDAC installer` for more info. On newer OS's, WDAC is installed as part of Windows.

Of your list, these are the only files that I would consider safe to distribute:

```
comdlg32.ocx
mscomctl.ocx
stdole2.tlb  (although, this REALLY shouldn't be necessary)
```

All of the other files are either part of Office, and should already be on the box, or are part of WDAC/MDAC.

If absolutely necessary, you can always install the Access 2000 Runtime. This would allow users that do not have Access 2000 installed to still be able to start your application.

Comment: We currently have the Access 2000 runtime installed for each user. Also we are currently using Windows XP for our OS. Sorry! I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Excellent; I'm not sure if the runtime will include MDAC components or not. If I had to bet, I would think that it does.

Comment: So, if you stop distributing all of those other files, except for the 3 that I listed, you should find your app still works, but you shouldn't have issues with Office 2007 trying to repair itself.